# Is it possible to define KMS Key ID for an EBS block device in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following situation where I need to create a launch configuration and along with it define an EBS block device. According the documentation https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#ebs_block_device it says that it is possible to encrypt the volume but it is not defined where to pass the kms key id. I'm afraid that this is not possible. so any idea how to achieve this

Comment: That's a launch config for AutoScaling. I note that EBS volumes are documented here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html.

Comment: yes I know but at the level of launch config you define an ebs block device where you can define the EBS properties

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13299 - find out already a discussion

Comment: However that discussion is valid only for instance. still remain valid the question in case of ASG

Comment: I don't think Auto Scaling actually exposes KMS encryption options for EBS volumes at this point. It simply offers encrypted: true/false, and AWS manages the keys. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_Ebs.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I'll add this for completeness.

Amazon recommends [Launch Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) over the older [Launch Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html) for creating Auto Scaling groups.

The Terraform resource [aws_launch_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template) allows setting of a [KMS key for EBS block devices](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#block-devices).

Answer (score 0):

cloudformation is also missing kmskeyid under launchconfig

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig-blockdev-template.html.

Strange that they don't expose that. 
They have it in the launchtemplate

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-ebs.html

and how to use it in cli

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/create-encrypted-amazon-ebs-volumes-custom-encryption-keys-launch-amazon-ec2-instance-2/